# Create Cron job that sends printed results from python script to list of users

Tags: cron

The title says it all.  I have a python script that prints out some data that I'd like to send to a list of users everyday.  What is the best way to do this?

Have no issues writing the python script and writing the cron job to schedule the python script to run, but the I'm having trouble writing the script to have the results sent on a regular interval.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe where exactly you require some help: sending the email, extracting the results, writing a script to do all that or creating the cron job itself?

Comment: edited my question above